# Can not create a table - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a table inside one of my forms, but I am having some errors (*Notice : Undefined offset: X in theme_tableselect()* ) and the content of my table is then wrong.

This is my code if someone could tell me what I miss :

```
<?php
$headers = array(
  t('Nom'), 
  t('Description'), 
  t('Nombre vidéos'), 
  t('Durée'), 
  t('Mode de lecture'),
  t('Date'),
  t('Actions'),
);

$form["gestionvideos_array"] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Playlists'),
  '#description' => t('Something'),
);
  foreach( $aPlaylist as $oPlaylist ){

    $rows = array(
      'Nom' => ucfirst($oPlaylist->sPlaylistName), 
      'Description' => $oPlaylist->sDescription, 
      'Nombre vidéos' => $oPlaylist->iTotal, 
      'Durée' => $oPlaylist->sDuree, 
      'Mode de lecture' => $oPlaylist->sMode,
      'Date' => $oPlaylist->dCreated,
      'Actions' => $oPlaylist->sAction,
    );
  }

  $form["gestionvideos_array"]["table"] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $headers,
    '#options' => $rows,
  );
  ?>
```

Comment: Use $rows[] = array(....);

Comment: I tried it, but the table is empty now...

Comment: Humm... how about removing the keys in the array and just use the values?

Comment: Glad to know it worked!